# Cron Expression for AWS SSM Statemanger

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-ssm

For AWS SSM state manager association, I have a cron expression to fire at 23:00 hours on every 14 days as below.

```
cron(0 23 1/14 * ? *)
```

On saving the changes, it gives error as:
InvalidSchedule: Schedule expression cron(0 23 1/14 * ? *) is currently not accepted

Thanks for your help.